# Collecting information from a step-form and displaying it in a confirmation page?

Tags: javascript, html

In the snippet below, I have a step-form. While submitting the content in the form and hitting next, the input values are being passed to the confirmation page at the end.

I'm trying to understand if this is the most efficient way to pass the information to the confirmation page?

```js
const previousButton = document.getElementById("previous")
const nextButton = document.getElementById("next")
const submitButton = document.getElementById('validate')
const form = document.getElementById('stepByStepForm')
const dots = document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar__dot')
const numberOfSteps = 5
let currentStep = 1

for(let i = 0 ; i < dots.length ; ++i){
   dots[i].addEventListener('click', ()=>{
     goToStep(i+1) 
   })
}

previousButton.onclick = goPrevious
nextButton.onclick = goNext


function goNext(e) {
   e.preventDefault()
   currentStep += 1
   goToStep(currentStep)
}

function goPrevious(e) {
   e.preventDefault()
   currentStep -= 1
   goToStep(currentStep)
}

function goToStep(stepNumber){   
   currentStep = stepNumber
   
   let inputsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName('step')
   let inputs = document.getElementsByClassName(`step${currentStep}`)
   let indicators = document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar__dot')
   
   for(let i = indicators.length-1; i >= currentStep ; --i){
      indicators[i].classList.remove('full')
   }
   
   for(let i = 0; i < currentStep; ++i){
      indicators[i].classList.add('full')
   }
   
   //hide all input
   for (let i = 0; i < inputsToHide.length; ++i) {
      hide(inputsToHide[i])
   }
   
   //only show the right one
   for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
      show(inputs[i])
   }
   
   //if we reached final step
   if(currentStep === numberOfSteps){
      enable(previousButton)
      disable(nextButton)
      show(submitButton)
   }
   
   //else if first step
   else if(currentStep === 1){
     disable(previousButton)
      enable(next)
      hide(submitButton)
   }
   
   else {
      enable(previousButton)
      enable(next)
      hide(submitButton)
   }
}

function enable(elem) {
   elem.classList.remove("disabled");
   elem.disabled = false;
}

function disable(elem) {
   elem.classList.add("disabled");
   elem.disabled = true;
}

function show(elem){
   elem.classList.remove('hidden')
}

function hide(elem){
   elem.classList.add('hidden')
}

//collect inputs
next.addEventListener('click', function() {
   const fNameInput = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
   document.getElementById('fNameOutput').textContent = fNameInput;   
   
   const lNameInput = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
   document.getElementById('lNameOutput').textContent = lNameInput;
   
   const emailInput = document.getElementById('mail').value;
   document.getElementById('emailOutput').textContent = emailInput;
   
   const phoneInput = document.getElementById('phone').value;
   document.getElementById('phoneOutput').textContent = phoneInput;
   
   const addressInput = document.getElementById('address').value;
   document.getElementById('addressOutput').textContent = addressInput;
   
   const countryInput = document.getElementById('country').value;
   document.getElementById('countryOutput').textContent = countryInput;
   
   const colorInput = document.getElementById('color').value;
   document.getElementById('colorOutput').textContent = colorInput;
   
   const animalInput = document.getElementById('animal').value;
   document.getElementById('animalOutput').textContent = animalInput;      
});

submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #A2C7E5;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.button {
  width: 140px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background-color: #ff8552;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #ff4f06;
}
.button.disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.button.disabled:hover {
  background-color: #ff8552;
}

.form {
  width: 20em;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5em;
  padding: 5em;
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  color: #33312E;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}
.form .progress-bar {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 3.5em;
}
.form .progress-bar li.progress-bar__dot {
  display: block;
  width: 0.6em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 0.6em;
  border: 0.1em solid #ff8552;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.form .progress-bar li.progress-bar__dot.full {
  background-color: #ff8552;
}
.form .progress-bar li.progress-bar__connector {
  display: block;
  width: 5em;
  border-radius: 1000em;
  height: 0.1em;
  background-color: #ff8552;
  margin-top: 0.35em;
}
.form label {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.form input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.3em;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 1em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}
.form input:focus {
  border: none;
}
.form .button-group {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.form button#validate {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #1A936F;
  width: 12em;
}
.form button#validate:hover {
  background-color: #12684e;
}
```

```html
<form id="stepByStepForm" class="form">
   <ul class="progress-bar">
      <li class="progress-bar__dot full"></li>
      <li class="progress-bar__connector"></li>
      <li class="progress-bar__dot"></li>
      <li class="progress-bar__connector"></li>
      <li class="progress-bar__dot"></li>
      <li class="progress-bar__connector"></li>
      <li class="progress-bar__dot"></li>
      <li class="progress-bar__connector"></li>
      <li class="progress-bar__dot"></li>
   </ul>

   <div class="step step1">
      <div class="input-group">
         <label for="firstname">First name</label>
         <input type="text" value="James" name="firstname" id="firstname">
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
         <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
         <input type="text" value="Smith" name="lastname" id="lastname">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="step step2 hidden">
      <div class="input-group">
         <label for="mail">E-mail</label>
         <input type="mail" value="jamessmith@gmail.com" name="mail" id="mail">
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
         <label for="phone">Phone</label>
         <input type="text" value="602-379-1395" name="phone" id="phone">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="step step3 hidden">
      <div class="input-group">
         <label for="address">Address</label>
         <input type="text" value="221B Baker Street" name="address" id="address">
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
         <label for="country">Country</label>
         <input type="text" value="United States" name="country" id="country">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="step step4 hidden">
      <div class="input-group">
         <label for="color">Favorite Color</label>
         <input type="text" value="Blue" name="color" id="color">
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
         <label for="animal">Favorite Animal</label>
         <input type="text" value="Lion" name="animal" id="animal">
      </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="step step5 hidden">
      <h4>Name:</h4>
      <p><strong>First Name:</strong> <span id="fNameOutput"></span></p>
      <p><strong>Last Name:</strong> <span id="lNameOutput"></span></p>
      <hr>
      <h4>Contact:</h4>
      <p><strong>Email:</strong> <span id="emailOutput"></span></p>
      <p><strong>Phone:</strong> <span id="phoneOutput"></span></p>
      <hr>
      <h4>Location:</h4>
      <p><strong>Address:</strong> <span id="addressOutput"></span></p>
      <p><strong>Country:</strong> <span id="countryOutput"></span></p>
      <hr>
      <h4>Attributes:</h4>
      <p><strong>Favorite Color:</strong> <span id="colorOutput"></span></p>
      <p><strong>Favorite Animal:</strong> <span id="animalOutput"></span></p>      
   </div>   

   <div class="button-group">
      <button id="previous" class="disabled button" disabled>
         previous
      </button>
      <button id="next" class="button">
         next
      </button>
   </div>
   <div class="button-group">
      <button id="validate" type="submit" class="hidden button">
         Submit
      </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 problems:

- In this part `next.addEventListener('click', function() {...}`, it updates all texts every time the next button is pressed.
- `document.getElementById(ID_NAME).textContent = VALUE;` is written repeatedly; It is not that bad but there are more readable ways.
- The confirmation textContents are not updated when the last dot is clicked.

---

First, make a function to update texts. To avoid writing similar code repeatedly, you can use an *Object* for ids and *for...of* to implement updating the text contents.

```js
function updateConfirmText() {
  const map = {
    firstname: 'fNameOutput',
    lastname: 'lNameOutput',
    mail: 'emailOutput',
    phone: 'phoneOutput',
    address: 'addressOutput',
    country: 'countryOutput',
    color: 'colorOutput',
    animal: 'animalOutput'
  };

  for (const [input, output] of Object.entries(map)) {
    document.getElementById(output).textContent = document.getElementById(input).value;
  }
}
```

Second, call the function in the if statement that you have already written.

```js
  //if we reached final step
  if (currentStep === numberOfSteps) {
    enable(previousButton)
    disable(nextButton)
    show(submitButton)

    updateConfirmText(); // Add
  }
```

I hope it works

Comment: Those options seem to be removing the ability to click on one of the dots to go back to the form and make any edits. Could it be the `if` statement?

Comment: It doesn't happen to me. By the way your and my code have the same problem.  The confirmation textContents aren't updated when the last dot is clicked. We have to fix it.

Comment: My above issue was fixed.

Comment: I set up the demo snippet to have `value` instead of `placeholder`, but that was to make the demo easier to use. If you change all the `value` attributes to `placeholder` and fill in the inputs manually, then the last dot doesn't update. I need to find a way to make each dot behave like the next button.